# Flutter firestore query WHERE clause

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I had the below code working by selecting a document using the firestore Document ID:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("table_name").doc(routeData['id']);
```

But if I replace that line with the line below to search by a field name then it breaks:

```
final Query docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("table_name")
  .where("id",isEqualTo: "gze1thwyhreqpbspu611aa3ejmhemxkthphyq3kugp5vqm75fwv");
```

and gives the following error:

> lib/main.dart:143:22: Error: The argument type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?'.

Please could you help me resolve?

This is the code:

```
class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  Map routeData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    routeData = ModalRoute
        .of(context)
        ?.settings
        .arguments as Map;
    print(routeData);

    // final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("jet").doc(routeData['id']);
    final Query docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("table_name").where("id",isEqualTo: "gze1thwyhreqpbspu611aa3ejmhemxkthphyq3kugp5vqm75fwv");

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: docRef.get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Waiting for future..."),
              // title: Text(data?["name"]),
            ),
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Error"),
            ),
            body: Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}")),
          );
        } else {

          print(snapshot.data!.data());
          final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(data?["name"]),
          ),

          body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            // reg, type, country, dlastupd
            children:  [
              Text("Region: " + data?["reg"]),
              Text("Country: " + data?["country"]),
              Text("Type: " + data?["type"]),
              Text("Last updated (red text): " + DateFormat('d MMMM y').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data?['dlastupd'] * 1000))),
            ],
          )
          )
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet reads a single document, so you get a `DocumentSnapshot` as the result.

Your second code snippet executes a query, which may result in multiple documents, so you get a `QuerySnapshot` as the result.

These two types are not the same, so your code needs to handle them differently.

---

First you need to change

```
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
```

To:

```
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
```

---

Then you need to change how you handle the data, since you can now get multiple documents.

If you **know** yourself that there can be at most one resulting document, you can do this to just process that single document from the `QuerySnapshot`:

```
} else {
  var querySnapshot = snapshot.data!
  var docs = querySnapshot.docs;
  final data = docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  ...
```

If there may be multiple results, you'll need to change the code to handle those multiple results.  I typically use `ListView.builder` for that, as you can for example see in this [code snippet on Zapp.run](https://zapp.run/edit/nanochat-zp006gwp106?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart:5207-5878)